# How to get access to the Vue Router custom props via composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

Vue Router doc [states](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) that custom object can be passed to the component via `props` key.

> When props is an object, this will be set as the component props
> as-is. Useful for when the props are static.

I my particular use case, I want to pass some additional args that cannot be obtained from URL, neither I want to use a computed property. So, here's a route list:

```js
routes: [
  {
    path: '/map',
    name: 'map',
    component: () => import('../pages/MapPage.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: 'xxx', component: XXXMap, props: { crumbs: [{ label: 'XXX i18n name' }] } },
      { path: 'yyy', component: YYYMap, props: { crumbs: [{ label: 'YYY i18n name' }] } },
      { path: 'zzz', component: ZZZMap, props: { crumbs: [{ label: 'ZZZ i18n name' }] } },
      // ...
    ]
  }
]
```

However, when I'm trying to obtain route args via composition API, I always get either `undefined` or a Typescript warning like `Property "whatever" does not exist on type`. Route params are also empty.

```js
export default {
  setup(props) {
    const crumbs = toRef(props, 'crumbs')

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(crumbs)
    })
  }
}
```

Is it even possible, preferably via the `<script setup>` syntax?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, it seems that I actually need `meta` property, which works and the issue is the incomplete and misguiding Vue Router doc.